# Data model designing for ERP modules

Tags: erp

**Requirement:** 
Need to design a data model for few ERP modules AP,AR,PO,OM,BOM,WIP,MTL

**Description:** 
This requirement is to collect all the important ERP module tables and design a sample model. Example: I'm going to create a data model for PO module, I will collect all the important PO and it's relevant table and take the necessary column and build a PO module. Output result: PO module will have all PO related data.

**Help:** 
Any once faced similar requirement? Kindly guide me on the above your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thilak, The best approach is to understand the business process first. How PO Module works in company in retail industry will be completely different with those in energy industry.

Always use normalization. Some data model might seems to have only one information while they can be many, e.g: One of 3 row of item in Purchase Order seems to have only one 'Required Date', while it might be many 'Required Date' with diff Qty, and distributed to many Warehouse.

There are many possibilities of those stuff, so having your application apply the standard behavior, but adjusted to the industry needs, is crucial part to define how your data model will look like.